# rails create controller for model "friendship"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make "relationship" between two models. I have model User, model Prog, model Relationship. I tied them up with has_many :through relationships.

I want to have button_to add Prog to User. I stopped at Relationship controller create. Do I use build method?

```
 <%= link_to "+ Add Programme", :controller => "relationships", :action => "create", :method => "post", :id => @prog.id %>

def create
 @relationship = @user.relationships.build(params[:relationship])
  if @relationship.save
   redirect_to user_url
  end
end
```

Obviously something is wrong here and I don't understand what.

Comment: Did you add 
belongs_to :user and belongs_to :prog in relationship model?

Comment: I did, I think problem is in the create controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For relationship to undestand how to make association you need to pass @user.id. In your button_to pass second id like:

```
<% @prog.users.each do |user| %>
 <%= button_to "+ Add Programme", :controller => "relationships", :action => "create", :method => "post", prog_id: @prog.id, user_id: user.id %>
<% end %>
```

and in create action

```
def create
 @user = params[user_id]
  @relationship = @user.relationships.build(params[:relationship])
    if @relationship.save
  ....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def create
  @prog = Prog.find(params[:id])
  current_user.progs << @prog 
  redirect_to user_url
end
```

However if relationships don't have any views and you only use this to create relationsships between users, then consider moving this action to the user or prog controller. Maybe just use the update action on the user. I better solution would be something like this:

```
# in user show.html.erb or wherever you want it
<%= form_for @user do |f|
  <%= f.hidden_field "prog_ids[]", @prog.id %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# In user controller
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to user_url(@user)
  end
end
```